# Two dataframe columns to row and column index with third column as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
               x     y     error
(1, 1)         1.0   1.0  0.062532
(1.0, 2.0)     1.0   2.0  0.050991
(1.0, 3.0)     1.0   3.0  0.028133
(1.0, 4.0)     1.0   4.0  0.023807
...
(99.0, 20.0)  99.0  20.0  0.019846
(99.0, 21.0)  99.0  21.0  0.135257
(99.0, 22.0)  99.0  22.0  0.230610
(99.0, 23.0)  99.0  23.0  0.481302
```

I want a new dataframe like this, such that i can make a heatmap easily with seaborn

```
    X  1   2   3 .. 99
Y   
1      erros....
2
3
4
..
49
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.pivot(index='y', columns='X', values='error')
```

You can get more examples on pivot table in pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Comment: Thank you, i was lookin for the pivot keyword